# Deploying to Website or Virtual Directory

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, installation

Is it acceptable to package a web service application in an installer that can only install to a virtual directory of an existing website? And not to its own website from the installer?

Comment: Is this a question of ethics? I think that's entirely up to you, in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's acceptable depends on what the application does. If it's inherently bound to/dependent on an existing app, it might be OK. What will make sense to the customer?

Comment: Problem is the installer that comes with Visual Studio only outputs to a virtual directory. So I am wondering if this will suffice, or if I am going to hit problems later - when we deploy to real customers who might insist of having the web site installed to its own website.

Comment: The more I think about your answer, the more I realise its very true. I just know I am going to run into anal retentiveness over not having an installer that can install to a base web site.